# bailiff in Britain

Tags: word-meaning

One of the definitions for [bailiff in the Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bailiff) is

> *British* A sheriff's officer who executes writs and processes and carries out distraints and arrests.

I've tried to find the corresponding meaning [inside the huge list of meanings given for bailiff in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bailiff). Is the meaning given by the Oxford Dictionary identical to

> (Britain) A high bailiff: an officer of the county courts responsible
>   for executing warrants and court orders, appointed by the judge and
>   removable by the Lord Chancellor.

? I am unsure because the Oxford Dictionary mentions a sheriff and wiktionary mentions a judge and the Lord Chancellor.

There is also the following definition inside Wiktionary, and I wonder if the one from Oxford Dictionary applies to this.

> (Britain) A bumbailiff: a deputy bailiff charged with debt collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [etymological description](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bailiff) shows, the term may refer to different roles:

> c. 1300 (early 13c. in surnames), "***subordinate administrative or judicial officer of the English crown, king's officer in a county, hundred, or other local district;" also "keeper of a royal castle;" also "minor judiciary officer under a sheriff,"  who serves writs, etc.;***
>
> from Old French baillif (12c., nominative baillis) "administrative official, deputy," from Vulgar Latin *baiulivus "official in charge of a castle," from Latin baiulus "porter" (see bail (n.1)). From early 14c. as "agent of a lord, overseer of an estate" who directs operations, collects rents, etc.; also used in Middle English of an elected official in a town.

Source:  Etymonline

As from the Oxford Learner's Dictionary, the main current usages are:

> (British English) a law officer whose job is to take the possessions and property of people who cannot pay their debts
>    - *The bailiffs seized the car and house.
>   Their landlord has threatened to send in the bailiffs if they don’t pay their rent.*
>
> (British English) a person employed to manage land or a large farm for somebody else
>
> (North American English) an official who keeps order in court, takes people to their seats, watches prisoners, etc.

Comment: How many profiles do you have on this site, Josh?